Cloud Run long CPU times and poor initial performance for Python app
I have a function that uses BigQuery API to retrieve a dataset and write it to a dataframe.  Its a large dataframe of about 500k rows.  It only runs at start time and locally takes about 27 seconds with CPU time of 3.5.

  _     ._   __/__   _ _  _  _ _/_   Recorded: 17:04:44  Samples:  997
 /_//_/// /_\ / //_// / //_'/ //     Duration: 27.211    CPU time: 3.546
/   _/                      v4.6.2

Program: main.py

27.210 get_users_list  users.py:17
├─ 19.891 QueryJob.to_dataframe  google/cloud/bigquery/job/query.py:1822
│     [73 frames hidden]  google, requests, urllib3, http, sock...
│        8.765 _SSLSocket.read  <built-in>
│        6.331 lock.acquire  <built-in>
├─ 6.220 Client.query  google/cloud/bigquery/client.py:3371
│     [25 frames hidden]  google, requests, urllib3, http, sock...
│        5.928 _SSLSocket.read  <built-in>
└─ 0.837 SeriesGroupBy.idxmax  pandas/core/groupby/generic.py:1182
      [15 frames hidden]  pandas, <built-in>

The same code running in Cloud Run takes around 380 seconds and CPU time 190.  I've tried going from 4 CPUs to 8 and from 4G RAM to 32 and the numbers basically stay the same. My question here is not so much about code optimization but how to understand why the performance difference is so huge in Cloud Run and am looking for recommendations to make it better.  My local environment is an Apple M1 MBP with 32G.  Given that changing my runtime environment in Cloud Run doesn't affect the numbers - any thoughts on why this is?
Code for reference is simply:
        bq_client = st.session_state.bq_client

        sql_query = f"""
                SELECT *
                    FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.unity_user_progress`
                WHERE
                    first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
                """

        df_unity_users = bq_client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()

        sql_query = f"""
                SELECT *
                    FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.cr_first_open`
                WHERE
                    first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
                """

        df_cr_first_open = bq_client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()

        sql_query = f"""
                    SELECT *
                        FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.cr_user_progress`
                    WHERE
                        first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
                    """

        df_cr_users = bq_client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()


        sql_query = f"""
                SELECT *
                    FROM `dataexploration-193817.user_data.cr_app_launch`
                WHERE
                    first_open BETWEEN PARSE_DATE('%Y/%m/%d','{start_date}') AND CURRENT_DATE() 
                """

        df_cr_app_launch = bq_client.query(sql_query).to_dataframe()
    


Please add a minimal reproducible example.

Can you share the location of your Cloud Run and your BigQuery dataset? Can you also share a piece of code?

Adding CPU cores does not speed-up I/O operations (which is the bottleneck here, I guess). You can check if I am right on some significantly worse than current local machine.

@dankal444 how do you speed up I/O in Cloudrun?  That is the ultimate question.

@guillaume-blaquiere They are private datasets and environments, so can't really share.  Adding the code now.  But the question is really about why one environment is so much slower than another and how to fix that - not about code optimization.

I see now you have couple of queries. Do all queries slow down equally or maybe just one of them?

Do you run the queries in the same project? Do you have reservation? Do you have concurrent job in BigQuery at the same time you start your Cloud Run? Many things can impact the BigQuery performances. In addition, your local workstation is much powerful that the cloud one (even if you have the same number of CPU, your local CPU runs 25% faster (about 4Ghz) than those in the cloud (about 3Ghz, sometime less!)) https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/cpu-platforms

@guillaumeblaquiere - Yes, same project.  No reservation. No concurrent job running.  Same performance always.  What I want to know is is it possible to configure Cloud Run to have the same performance as the local machine?

@dankal444 - They are all slow.  The question is, giving this exact code, how can I configure Cloud Run to perform at the same level as the local machine?  Maybe not possible and I should look at a different hosting environment.

You can't run at scale thousand of CPU as weak as yours on your laptop. Industry use robust CPU, not the same as you find in your laptop. They are design to run 24/7, with high intensity and with constraint environment (cooling, space,...). That why, any provider will be able to deliver extra fast CPU as you have on  your laptop.

I don't know why you put all your data in a dataframe. But I can assure you that it's not a good idea, because it's not scalable. The more the data, the more memory is required. If you really want to use Pandas and dataframe feature, I strongly recommend to have a look to BigQuery BigFrame library: https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigframes/latest

@guillaumeblaquiere  Because all that data is loaded to view on a dashboard, that requires all of it.  I tried bigframe.  Once I finally got it to work (it supports a subset of pandas) , it was actually slower.  And actually not usable because this data gets serialized into cache (streamlit) which also wasn't supported.

Nothing magic!!! First, I agree, BigFrame support only a subset of Pandas API. It's getting better, but could be inefficient for you. However, the main advantage is to let data in BigQuery and to query them only when need, on demand. But because the query is made on demand, the data are not already there, in memory and already loaded as you do. it's normal! It saves resource, allow you processing higher volume of data (without putting them in memory) but it's slower. Nothing magic! You must accept tradeoff, select yours!

@guillaumeblaquiere - Yes indeed!  I decided to go with concurrency and multi threaded loading the data.  I cut the entire time by 75% so I'm satisfied with that route.
